# How to add pooled imputation regression results to stargazer table

Tags: r, regression, imputation, stargazer, r-mice

I have imputed some NAs in my data, calculated a regression model and would like to present the results in a HTML table. I know how to do this for a regular model.

```
library(stargazer)

mydf <- iris

mydf_nonmice_model <- lm(
  Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width + Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width,
  data = mydf)

stargazer(mydf_nonmice_model, type = "html", out = "mice_reg.html")
```

However, when I try to do the same thing for model results obtained from MICE imputation, I can't do it.

```
library(mice)
library(stargazer)
mydf <- iris

# create some NAs
l <- nrow(mydf)
set.seed(1)
indeces <- sample(1:l, l/3)
mydf$Sepal.Length[indeces] <- NA

# impute data with 30 variations
m <- 30
mydf_mice <- mice::mice(data=mydf, m=m, maxit=10, seed=1, print=F)

# create models for imputed data
# (I know that you can also do this using 'with()', but the code below works ok for me)
mydf_mice_models <- lapply(1:m, function(i) {
  lm(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width + Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width,
     data = mice::complete(data = mydf_mice, i))
})

# look at the results
mice::pool(mydf_mice_models)

# creating a stargazer table gives an error
stargazer(
  mice::pool(mydf_mice_models),
  type = "html",
  out = "mice_reg.html")
```

The stargazer command gives me an error:

```
Error in start.lines[table.number]:length(all.latex.code) : 
  argument of length 0
```

So, is there a way to make model results of MICE imputed regressions display the same way as regular ones using stargazer? Many thanks in advance for any and all tips you might have!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to call `stargazer()` on one of the models from single imputed dataset (e.g., `mydf_mice_models[[1]]`) and you can replace the coefficient, standard errors, t-statistics and p-values with values calculated from the pooled model.

```r
library(mice)
library(stargazer)
project.org/package=stargazer
mydf <- iris

# create some NAs
l <- nrow(mydf)
set.seed(1)
indeces <- sample(1:l, l/3)
mydf$Sepal.Length[indeces] <- NA

# impute data with 30 variations
m <- 30
mydf_mice <- mice::mice(data=mydf, m=m, maxit=10, seed=1, print=F)

# create models for imputed data
# (I know that you can also do this using 'with()', but the code below works ok for me)
mydf_mice_models <- lapply(1:m, function(i) {
  lm(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width + Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width,
     data = mice::complete(data = mydf_mice, i))
})

mydf_mice_models2 <- lapply(1:m, function(i) {
  lm(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width + Sepal.Width,
     data = mice::complete(data = mydf_mice, i))
})



# look at the results
pool.mod <- mice::pool(mydf_mice_models)
smry <- summary(pool.mod)
pool.mod2 <- mice::pool(mydf_mice_models2)
smry2 <- summary(pool.mod2)

b <- smry$estimate
names(b) <- smry$term
se <- smry$std.error
t_stat = smry$statistic
p_val <- smry$p.value

b2 <- smry2$estimate
names(b2) <- smry2$term
se2 <- smry2$std.error
t_stat2 = smry2$statistic
p_val2 <- smry2$p.value
```

Answering the last question in the comments, you can use `add.lines()` to add to the table, just pass in the values you would calculate for the pooled model AIC and LL.

```r
stargazer(mydf_mice_models[[1]],
         mydf_mice_models2[[1]], 
         coef = list(b, b2), 
         se = list(se, se2),
         t = list(t_stat, t_stat2), 
         p = list(p_val, p_val2),
         add.lines = list(c("AIC", 1.234, 3.456), 
                          c("log likelihood", 5.678, 6.789)),
         keep.stat = "n", 
         type = "text")
#> 
#> ===========================================
#>                    Dependent variable:     
#>                ----------------------------
#>                        Petal.Length        
#>                     (1)            (2)     
#> -------------------------------------------
#> Petal.Width       1.507***      2.156***   
#>                   (0.068)        (0.053)   
#>                                            
#> Sepal.Length      0.715***                 
#>                   (0.058)                  
#>                                            
#> Sepal.Width      -0.634***      -0.355***  
#>                   (0.072)        (0.092)   
#>                                            
#> Constant           -0.287       2.258***   
#>                   (0.298)        (0.314)   
#>                                            
#> -------------------------------------------
#> AIC                1.234          3.456    
#> log likelihood     5.678          6.789    
#> Observations        150            150     
#> ===========================================
#> Note:           *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot for your helpful answer! I have a small follow-up question. In my analysis I have not one, but multiple imputed (and non-imputed) regression model results. How would I go about combining them into the same stargazer table? My idea so far was to combine them into the same vector, so for example `b <- c(smry[,"estimate"], smry2[,"estimate"])` and then add another placeholder model inside stargazer, like you did with `mydf_mice_models[[1]]`. However, when I do this some coefficents seem to be wrong.

Comment: Almost, instead of a vector, you need a list, where each element is the coefficients from a different model e.g., `b <- list(smry[,"estimate"], smry2[,"estimate"])`. Each element of the list will be a different column in the stargazer table.

Comment: Great, I think I will be able to construct my table the way I want now. A bit more on-topic, I noticed that while the extracted estimates are the same as those in the summary of the pooled results, the p-values are not. `b == summary(pool.mod)$estimate # TRUE` whereas `p_val ==  summary(pool.mod)$p.value # FALSE`. Is there a problem?

Comment: Apologies, my p-value calculation was off.  I've fixed it in the answer.  I also updated it to work with two models.

Comment: I have another small follow-up question: I noticed that stargazer will calculate log likelihoods and AIC based on the models supplied as the first argument to its function. Usually it's nice that this is done for you, but as the `mydf_mice_models[[1]]` here is just a placeholder and doesn't represent the 29 other imputed models' goodness of fit value, this becomes a problem. Could I instead pass extract AIC or loglik and pass it directly to stargazer as another list or vector? I haven't found a way to do this yet, but I would really like to include this important information.

Comment: @degeso I updated the answer.  TL;DR you can use `add.lines()` to add values into the table.

Comment: That's great, thank you so much! This solves all my problems